# Is Twips is Supported in .NET?

Tags: vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I am working in a VB6 to DotNet Migration project.Here in our VB 6 project they are calculating the some mouse move events in Twips, but when it is converted in VB.NET is giving the mouse move values as pixels.Does the twips is Supported in .NET?

Can any one tell me ?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044397/how-do-i-convert-twips-to-pixels-in-net Seems to be a duplicate.

Comment: @agrothe I have tried that too. but no use

Comment: Is the code giving an error? If so, post the code that's giving an error. Twips are replaced by pixels in .NET, so you _should_ refactor to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the sources I can find, Twips is not supported in .NET. There are some compatibility extensions, but I think the best approach is to refactor the twips out to use the .NET pixels instead. The refactoring is a pain, but in the long run, the project will just work better.

[Twips and .NET](http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2007/09/20/Twips-and-NET.aspx)

[VB .NET Switches to Pixel from Twip](http://visualbasic.about.com/cs/visualbasicfaq/a/dykpixeltwip.htm)

Someone else may have more information that I've missed.