# Printing custom paper size to an impact printer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, dot-matrix

I'm printing to an impact printer, loaded with **8.5 x 8.5** inch paper.  When I print, the printer ejects 11 inches instead of 8.5.

```
PageMediaSize pageSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.Unknown, element.Width, element.Height);

PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintTicket.PageMediaSize = pageSize;
Console.WriteLine(dialog.PrintableAreaHeight); // 816, good!
dialog.PrintQueue = myQueue;                   // selected from a combobox
Console.WriteLine(dialog.PrintableAreaHeight); // 1056 :(

dialog.PrintVisual(element, description);
```

Using "[How do I convert Twips to Pixels in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044397/how-do-i-convert-twips-to-pixels-in-net)" I've determined that 8.5 inches is 816 pixels, which is the size of my `element.Width` and `element.Height`.  I'm setting a new `PageMediaSize`, but this seems to have no effect, `dialog.PrintableAreaHeight` is still ends up at 1056 when I set the queue on the dialog.

If I do `dialog.ShowDialog()`, manually pick my printer, and manually find and change Paper Size in my printer's advanced settings, then `dialog.PrintableAreaHeight` properly reflects the change.

This page http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/set-printdialogs-default-page-size-168976.aspx suggests that I can only set a `PageMediaSize` supported by my printer. Using the `GetPrintCapabilities` function on my `PrintQueue`, I see a list of 10 or so page sizes, none of which are 8.5 x 8.5. This is the same list I see when I go to my printer's advanced settings in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below, it sets paper size as required

```
        var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
        var labelPaperSize = new PaperSize { RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A6, Height = 148, Width = 105 };
        printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = labelPaperSize;
        var labelPaperSource = new PaperSource { RawKind = (int)PaperSourceKind.Manual };
        printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = labelPaperSource;
        if (printerSettings.CanDuplex)
        {
            printerSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Default;
        }
```

Comment: Incomplete solution and explanation