# convert pixel to twips

Tags: c#, pixel

I have a project in VB6 that I need to convert to C#, this project uses the TextWidth Method and I replaced it with TextRenderer.MeasureText Method in C# which return the size in pixel but I need to convert it to twips for other uses, How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If you're converting everything to C#, why do you need the twips value? Surely, wherever you were previously *using* this value, the replacement for *that* code is going to want pixel values instead of twips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an extension that holds the logic to convert pixels to twips.
See [How do I convert Twips to Pixels in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044397/how-do-i-convert-twips-to-pixels-in-net)
For an example on how to do it.

Comment: thanks here is me implementation:   public static int ConvertPixelsToXTwips(this Graphics source, int pixel)
        {

            return (int)((double)pixel / ((1.0 / 1440.0) * source.DpiX));   
        }
        but now i have a new problem, i found out that the numbers that vb6 TextWidth return are different from the results of TextRenderer.MeasureText even after the convertion

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the helper method `Support.TwipsPerPixelX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.support.twipsperpixelx.aspx).

Comment: I am working with 64 bit process and it is unsupported as you can see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee839621(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Where are you using Twips? Can't you just use a constant like `1440/ScreenDPI`?